# path to persistent disk - to be accessed after shutdown

Tags: virtual-machine, storage, google-compute-engine

I have started a VM and want to make sure that data stored on a persistent disk can be accessed after the machine is shut down.

Should I store the file in a specific folder?

Answer (score 1):

If your data are stored on a persistent disk, to access the data the disk has to be attached to a running VM machine. Therefore, if you want to have access to your data while the machine is off, store your data on the [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).